# Tabulator - keep column minimum size to fit data when in fitColumns layout mode

Tags: tabulator

When using the **FitColumns** option, is there a way to keep the minimum data size even if the width is narrow?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the minimum width of a column using the `minWidth` property in the column definition:

```js
{title:"name", field:"name", minWidth:120} //set minimum column width to 120px
```

So if you know how wide the data will be then this will work nicely for you.

If you don't know the data width then i'm afraid not, the `fitData` layout mode is designed to ensure that columns are resized to fit their data, the `fitColumns` layout mode prioritises fitting the columns into the table regardless of how well the data fits in that column.

Though it does have some fairly extensive configuration controls to give you more control on how it shrinks and grows each column with the `widthShrink`  and `widthGrow` options.

Full details on how to configure the `fitColumns` layout mode can be found in the [Layout Documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/layout#fittowidth)